# Reading /sys/class files in Android without root permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions

I'm trying to read a system file: `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now`

What i've tried:

1. Easy and normal java way

   ```
   FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
   InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(fs);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr);

   //This code works on older devices.
   //When then executed returns Permissions denied
   ```
2. Copying the file in a writable directory

   ```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                   "cp",path,newPath);
   //When then executed returns Permissions denied
   ```
3. Reading file with cat

   ```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                   "cat",path);
   //When then executed returns Permissions denied
   ```

Yes i have read write permissions, yes i have runtime read write permissions, i can read and write files in the app folder and documents folder.

I think having su permissions this would be easy, but that's my last way.

Answer (score 0):

on Samsung with Combination Firmware you can access those areas with adb, like
$ adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now

on ZTE's you can *sometimes* access via FTM mode